# How to exclude first-parents from second-parents in git topological order?

Tags: git

I am trying to customize git topological commit ordering so that a second-parent gets shown only when there have been no such first-parent.
Here is a script for a set up:

```sh
touch a
git add a
git commit -m "a"

git checkout -b feature_b
touch b
git add b
git commit -m "b"

git checkout master
echo "1" > a
git commit -am "a1"

git checkout feature_b
git merge --no-ff -m "master to feature_b" master

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff -m "feature_b to master" feature_b
```

which results in

```sh
$ git log --graph --abbrev-commit --format=oneline
*   697e92f (HEAD -> master) feature_b to master
|\  
| *   2eaef1a (feature_b) master to feature_b
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | 2f83cbf a1
| * c4aa6df b
|/  
* d8f1101 a
```

**The question is how to tell git to list the commit "b" before "a1"?**
So that the output would look like that

```sh
*   697e92f (HEAD -> master) feature_b to master
|\  
| * 2eaef1a (feature_b) master to feature_b
| |\
| * c4aa6df b
| | |  
| |/
|/|
* | 2f83cbf a1
|/  
* d8f1101 a
```

The reason i am asking is that it is quite common to have merges back and force between master and release branches. And it seems more convenient not to re-order commits if possible. Moreover  the first commit "697e92f" explicitly states that "2eaef1a" comes after "2f83cbf". And since "c4aa6df" is a part of "2eaef1a" they should be displayed together.

Tried different git options but either it does not have one or i am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

it turned out that there is already a patch for Git which does exactly what i need. The patch was posted two months ago by Micha Nelissen.
Here is a [link](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190303103751.6523-1-nelissen.micha@gmail.com/T/#u).

It introduces a new option "--tree"

Here is how it works:

```sh
$ git log --tree --oneline
*   697e92f (HEAD -> master) feature_b to master
|\  
| * 2eaef1a (feature_b) master to feature_b
| * c4aa6df b
* 2f83cbf a1
* d8f1101 a
```

Thanks everybody for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  Git has `--first-parent`, which excludes all parents *except* the first, but it has no conditional "exclude first parent if there are more than 1" or "exclude all but the 2nd parent when the commit is a merge" options.

What you *can* do, though it is rather painful, is use `git rev-list` to enumerate the commits along with their parents:

```
git rev-list --parents HEAD
```

Read the output, one line at a time.  If the commit shown is a merge, remember its parents.  Exclude the first parent (and its own parents if desired) until the second parent's descendants return to that first parent.  Add `--topo-order` if you wish, to help constrain the order of emitted parents.  Take the output of your own algorithm, which selects the commits to show, and feed that to `git log --no-walk --stdin`.

Comment: agree that it's possible to implement the algorithm outside of Git.
i am sure that there exist some libraries which do exactly what you described.
what surprises me is why Git does not have such feature. Which from my point of view should be a default.

Answer (score -1):

> it seems more convenient not to re-order commits […] the first commit "697e92f" explicitly states that "2eaef1a" comes after "2f83cbf".

I don't see any re-ordering here.  Is your mom necessarily older than your dad because you always say "mom and dad"?  No.  Where you are on one list does not "explicitly state" where you belong on other lists.

> And since "c4aa6df" is a part of "2eaef1a" they should be displayed together.

`2f83` is just as much a part of `697e` as `c4aa` is a part of `2eae`. Both commits are necessarily separated to draw an ancestry link *that you explicitly requested*.

Basically, you've found a presentation constraint and built a fairly specious case for  "improving" a minor, secondary aspect of the history display by actively misrepresenting an explicitly-requested, major one.

Comment: Let me explain the re-ordering happening here.
Let's imagine you are a maintainer of the master branch.
The branch has two commits 2f83 and d8f1.
And more importantly there are no any other commits between those two.
It's your view of the world.
You receive a pull request and expects that after a merge the new commits are placed on top of yours.
In other words you expect that the history (ordering) is not changed.
Which is not the case with the current Git behaviour.
c4aa is palced between 2f83 and d8f1.

Comment: From a point of view of the feature_b maintainer the ordering is not changed.
But it would be more natural if the ordering of the source branch would be changed instead the one of the target branch.

Comment: I edited my original question and added a link between "2eae" and "2f83" to avoid possible confusion. 
The presence or the absence of the link is not essential for the question.

Comment: You're trying to read vastly different (or maybe just more) meaning into the graph sequencing than what's there.  The log's always no-commit-precedes-an-ancestor, after that the sequencing is in date or topological order.  If you don't ask, it's in date order, if neither a nor b are ancestor to the other they'll be listed, by default, newest-by-date-first.  If you fetch or push history from another repo into yours, the incoming commits aren't magically refreshed, they still have their commit dates, so date-ordered logs will show the new commits sequenced by date with the ones you already had.